# How to send file for download to user as a background process from Node.js/Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently using res.download() to send the the file, however when files are larger the request takes more than 30 seconds that causes request timeouts which is a problem for deployment.

Present code:

```
app.get('/download',(req,res) => {

censor(filePath);//function to process file before download

res.download(filePath,fileName, (err) => {

  if(err)
    console.log(err);

});
});
```

I would like to make sure that the download takes place under 30 secs, files are typically text files.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey guys, I realised that it was the censor function that was taking the bulk of the time and not the ers.download(), any ideas how could I put that in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) and `redis` to make a simple pattern of a queue. In this case your long time taking task will run "in the backgroud" and you won't block the Event Loop. Once the task is finished you can be notified about this fact and do something with it. Here is a nice article you can start with: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing